# Kubernetes pods using too much memory on larger machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am still kind of getting my feet under me with kubernetes. We have a spring-boot based app with ~17 microservices running on Kubernetes 1.4.2 on AWS. When I run this app on an AWS cluster of 4 m3.medium workers, my containers are all in the 200-300MB range of memory usage at rest (with a couple exceptions). For production I installed the same set of services on 4 m4.large workers and instantly my memory moved up to 700-1000MB of memory on the same containers with virtually identical specs. I am trying to figure out who is the offending party here - Springboot, Docker or Kubernetes.

Has anyone seen behavior like this before?

I know I can cap the resources using Kubernetes limits, but I really don't want to do that given that I know the application can run just fine on smaller machines and have a smaller footprint. Just looking for some advice on where the problem might be.

EDIT: One more piece or pertinent information. I am using CoreOS stable 1298.6.0 as the host OS image.

Comment: Had the exact same issue running akka workers on GKE. The pods will run just fine on n1.standard machines with a limit of 500mb, and when I moved them to n4.standard machines with a 2000mb limit they started breaching their limits and getting evicted (which is really something to look out from when memory usage goes haywire)

Comment: Does your application adjust the its resource usage (e.g., number of processes/threads) based on the machine capacity? If the application provides metrics, you can do a side-by-side comparison.

Comment: These are very clever questions I wish I could put to the test but this issue came up at my former job and so I no longer have access to their metrics. If I'll manage to reproduce I'll make sure I check these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem is that your processes inside the container see the total host RAM available as the RAM available for them.

If you use a bigger instance, the JVM will try to use even more RAM. You should try to limit your java virtual machine heap with -Xmx300m (adjust this value with what your app needs).
I recommend you to read [this](https://dzone.com/articles/java-inside-docker-what-you-must-know-to-not-fail) article where its explained in an easy and clean way.

Comment: This article helps, thanks. Interestingly there are still differences depending on the environment. I found that configuring using resource limits I could only get so small before the pod would terminate in k8s as OOM. If I set it as an env variable I could get smaller, but the memory was still surprisingly high.  For reference:
- Deployment spec  limits I could get no smaller than ~350MB (set resource request 175Mi/limit 350Mi)
-Setting using env variables (I set -Xms64m -Xmx128m) but on k8s itself the pod still hit ~290MB
- When unbounded on m3 machines the pods never went above 260MB

Comment: In case anyone else is interested one more note not addressed in the above article. You can further constrain memory in Java 8 using -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=<size>, but even with that there is some additional memory allocated to each container that seems to be related to the size of the machine on which it runs. Ultimately, I found Xmx + -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize + ~60-70MB gave me my total container size for my small services.

Comment: We have also used `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` as a JVM opt for the container.
This limits the amount it can used based on the `limit` set by the user, but is easily adjustable for testing etc.
Going over 80% is not advised, from what I have read on the subject